# How pass in data from a .txt file and construct them separately in a inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

i have created an inherited class and had placed the data in the same .txt file as the parent class. i need help in constructing the object from the txt file into the inherited class.This is the txt file

```
1101,Lemon Tea,2.00
1102,Green Tea,1.90
1103,Black Tea,2.50
1104,Milo,1.50
1201,Coca Cola,2.00
1202,Pepsi,2.00
1203,Whatever,2.10 
1204,Anything,2.10
2101,Unadon,8.50
2102,Tamagodon,7.50
2103,katsudon,8.10
2104,Oyakodon,7.80
2105,Ikuradon,8.00
2201,onigiri,10.00
2202,maki,9.50
2203,aburi sushi,6.50
2204,temari sushi,4.50
2205,oshi sushi,7.50
2301,kaarage,9.20
2302,gyuniku,9.50
2303,tempura,9.00
2304,unagi,8.00
5501,Bento Of the Year(kaarage bento),4.60,2017,1,1
5502,Winter Promotion(2x sake bento + 2x Ice Lemon Tea),25.00,2016,31,1
5503,Sushi Galore(all sushi For $30.00),30.00,2017,1,1
5504,New Year Special(4x bento + 4x Green Tea),35.00,2016,15,15
```

and this is my the inherited class

```
class Promotion : product
{
    private DateTime dateEnd;
    public Promotion(int sn, string n, double p, DateTime dt) : base(sn, n, p) 
    {
        dateEnd = dt;
    }
    public Promotion(DateTime dt)
    {
        dateEnd = dt;
    }
    public DateTime PromoType
    {
        get { return dateEnd; }
        set { dateEnd = value; }
    }

    public string getPromoInfo()
    {
        string info = base.product_info();
        info +=  dateEnd;
        return info;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: By the way the last line of your text file has an invalid date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as following...

```
string line;
List<product> promotions = new List<product>();

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\yourFile.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] words = line.Split(',');
    if(words.length == 4)
    {
        promotions.Add(new Promotion(words[0],words[1],words[2],words[3]));
    }
    else
    {
        promotions.Add(new product(words[0],words[1],words[2]));
    }
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: btw just asking since the list is in product class how do i access the method in the promotion class

Answer (score 0):

I would use a factory class to parse and create objects of type promotion.
The approach uses the yield return statement in order to read and process the file line by line. You could also read the file content at once as an alternative approach.

## The factory class:

```
public class PromotionFactory : IPromotionFactory
{
    public IEnumerable<IPromotion> Parse(string file)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(file));

        var result = new List<IPromotion>();
        foreach (var line in ReadFile(file))
        {
            var promotion = ParseLine(line);
            result.Add(promotion);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private IPromotion ParseLine(string line)
    {
        var segments = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (segments.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Could not read segments");

        var id = int.Parse(segments[0]);
        var name = segments[1];
        var price = decimal.Parse(segments[2]);

        DateTime? date = null;
        if (segments.Length > 3)
        {
            date = new DateTime(int.Parse(segments[3]), int.Parse(segments[5]), int.Parse(segments[4]));
        }

        return new Promotion(id, name, price, date);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ReadFile(string file)
    {
        string line;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {
                    yield return line;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## The Promotion class:

```
public class Promotion : Product, IPromotion
{
    public Promotion(int id, string name, decimal price, DateTime? date) : base (id, name, price)
    {
        Date = date;
    }

    public DateTime? Date { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.AppendLine("Promotion:");
        builder.AppendLine($"Id: {Id}");
        builder.AppendLine($"Name: {Name}");
        builder.AppendLine($"Price: {Price}");
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Date: {0}", Date != null ? Date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty));
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

## The calling class

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = string.Format("{0}//foobar.txt", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
        var factory = new PromotionFactory();

        var promotions = factory.Parse(file);

        promotions.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```